# Why does Asterisk ignore a dtmf code from a specific handset

Tags: asterisk, sip, dtmf

I'm running Asterisk 1.13. When two users enter dtmf 9 it gets ignored. 
I can see in the logs that Asterisk is receiving the dtmf but it doesn't do any action. Most phones that I have tries work fine. I see the following in the logs, but no action is taken.

```
[Apr 15 16:40:08] DEBUG[11094][C-00000018] res_rtp_asterisk.c: Creating BEGIN DTMF Frame: 57 (9), at x.x.x.x:37740
[Apr 15 16:40:08] DEBUG[11094][C-00000018] res_rtp_asterisk.c: Creating END DTMF Frame: 57 (9), at x.x.x.x:37740
```

Any ideas?

Comment: why you expect some action?

Comment: My dialplan defines some action. Or at least I thought it did. Turns out Wait() doesn't listen for dtmf to that was the fail. It's fixed.

Answer (score -1):

I had Wait() in the dialplan instead of WaitExten(). It therefore didn't listing at that time for input leading me down many rabbit holes. It's sorted now.